# How to set initial values of MDL slider programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

I am using Material Design Lite and I am setting up a slider with:

```
<input id='mapslider' class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider " type="range"
  min="0" max="100" value="25" tabindex="1">
```

During program execution I need to change the option values for `min` and `max` programmatically with javascript/jQuery but I can't find any reference on documentation. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Posting here for anybody's else need.

Once set the id for the slider (`id='mapslider'`), it's just a matter of referencing it as an object. So, to change the `max` option:

```
mapslider.max=120;
```

Trivial, but no documentation available on this.